# colorBOX separate class by id

Tags: php

Im currently using colorBOX where you can show pictures in other way ( just like shadowbox ).

I have an script code ( that detect's the class )

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
        });
    </script>

<a href="img_loc" class="group1">
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="img_loc"/>
</a>
```

My problem with this?
I have different cars on this website, and when i click for example Car1 pictures it will always show all the pictures available with the group1 class...

[Two different cars (show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUfnd.png)

My question:
Is there a way to add to the `script` like the `carID` and to the `class` add like `class="group1-"<?php echo $car->id ?>`

I don't know if you get the idea guys, sorry for the horrible spelling and thanks.

Comment: for example if i click car1, i will only display the images of the car 1, not all the cars images... so i was thinking about creating an extension lets say group1-$id

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the images being shown as a group, just remove the `rel` property from the Colorbox settings object.  For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".group1").colorbox();
    });
</script>
```

If you want the pictures grouped by car ID, you could give each link a cbox-data-rel attribute with your car ID, and Colorbox will group those images based on which share the same value.  For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".group1").colorbox();
    });
</script>
<a href='car1front.jpg' data-cbox-rel='333'>Car 1 front</a>
<a href='car1back.jpg' data-cbox-rel='333'>Car 1 back</a>
<a href='car2.jpg' data-cbox-rel='777'>Car 2</a>
```

The images car1front and car1back will be grouped together.